# How should I store a simple, time dependent, repetitive data type in drupal

Tags: entities

Im interested in collecting simple data series over time with Drupal. for instance, lets say a user wants to input a monetary amount the spend on a given item each day, and then track that over time. It seams like overkill to log the information as a node, or even an entity for that matter. What is a good way to store data of this nature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I last looked [webform](http://www.drupal.org/project/webform) submissions were not 1st class drupal citizens. This may have changed by now ...

I recommend using [ECK](http://www.drupal.org/project/eck); or using a custom [Content Type](https://drupal.org/node/21947) and [RabbitHole](http://www.drupal.org/project/rabbithole) (to hide the raw submissions if you dont want direct access to a single silly datum entry) to leverage Drupals core Field and Entity concepts for your data.

Then as an example I would recommend using the [Google Chart API](https://drupal.org/project/chart) along with [Views](http://www.drupal.org/project/views) for Drupal 7 to provide reports about your data over time -- depending on the complexity of your reports you may have to write a custom drupal module ...

But, this will be much more flexible than working with webform submission results in the long run.

Comment: ended up using eck

Answer (score 0):

I think [Webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) is what you are looking for. You make a form that user(s) can fill in and submit.

You can track the submissions over time, export them etc. There are lots of features you can do with webforms.

This is not a complete how-to for your question but you can take it as a start point. This way you don't create a node for each submission, but the form itself will be a node of type Webform.